# Connection status to Couchbase cluster

Tags: java, couchbase

How can monitoring status connection to couchbase cluster consisting few servers?
In docs to couchbase, class CouchbaseClaster doesn't have methods for checks connection status to cluster.
One of the solution it's checks to connection to bucket with CouchbaseManager.hasBucket(), but's think it's bad.
Maybe someone faced such a challenge?

PS: I apologize for possible mistakes, becouse I don't speak English well.

Answer (score 1):

I have found it unnecessary to monitor the database connection.  I instead add [error handling](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/java/handling-error-conditions.html) code to recover from such scenarios.

With the Couchbase Java SDK you can encounter a variety of exceptions. Some indicate temporary problems while others are permanent problems. For temporary problems, consider using a [retry mechanism](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/java/handling-error-conditions.html#story-h2-12).  For [permanent problems](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/java/handling-error-conditions.html#story-h2-11), log the error and trigger a notification through a monitoring application.

The Couchbase Java SDK will also log connectivity issues.  It periodically contacts the cluster to keep its Cluster Map up to date with any cluster changes. If it has problems doing that, it will log a message.

Comment: I'm developing a monitoring system, one of the metrics is the connection to the cluster. Therefore, I do not need to restore the connection when disconnected ;)

On this moment i search ClusterManager.info(). This  method returns, including the state of the node in the cluster. But this method now incorrect work, and bug(https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/JCBC-996) not fix.
At the moment I'm looking for the possibility of getting all nodes in a cluster. And depending on the status of the nodes, the cluster is operational or not.

Comment: @korevikov, perhaps you can use the REST APIs to accomplish your monitoring goals. Here's a project that monitors Couchbase nodes independently and publishes statistics to Nagios: [nagios-plugin-couchbase](https://github.com/couchbase-partners/nagios-plugin-couchbase), [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HY7YUKbQzWw).

Comment: To use the REST-API, you need to know the host to which to write the request. But since the cluster map is updated dynamically, at the time of the request, the server may be unavailable, and you need to get the current working server. I updated Couchbase Java API to last version(2.5.6), and in this release ClusterManager.info() working correctly. Becouse probles is solved.